Central limit theorem for two-sided Pareto distribution
I am trying to solve the following problem, which provides an example for a central limit theorem in spite of the fact that the variance is infinite. 
Consider the two-sided Pareto distribution with density
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
                 \frac{1}{|x|^3}, \enspace &\textrm{for} |x| \geq 1 \\
                 0, \enspace &\textrm{otherwise}.
          \end{cases} $$
(a) Prove that the characteristic function
$$ \varphi(t) = 1 - t^2 \left( \log \frac{1}{|t|} + O(1) \right) \enspace \textrm{as} \enspace t \rightarrow 0$$
(b) Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be independent, identically distributed random variable with the density as above. Prove that
$$ \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k}{\sqrt{n \log n}}  \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0,1) \enspace \textrm{as} \enspace n \rightarrow \infty.$$
I have proven (b) using (a). But I have no idea how to prove (a). I cannot use the same method as in the  proof of the central limit theorem, since the variance is not finite. And  I tried to calculate the characteristic function but this was not beneficial. 
Thank you very much for your help.

What have you tried?

I updated the question

$$
    \begin{align*}
      \varphi(t) &= \mathbb{E}\left(e^{itX}\right)\\
 &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{itx}f(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{-1} \dfrac{e^{itx}}{-x^3}dx + \int_1^\infty \dfrac{e^{itx}}{x^3}dx\\
   &= \int_{1}^\infty \dfrac{e^{-itx}}{x^3}dx + \int_1^\infty \dfrac{e^{itx}}{x^3}dx \\
 &= \int_1^\infty \dfrac{e^{itx} + e^{-itx}}{x^3}dx
    \end{align*}
$$
Since
$$
    e^{itx} = \cos(tx) + i \sin(tx), \text{ and } e^{-itx} = \cos(tx) - i\sin(tx)
$$
we have
$$
    \varphi(t) = 2 \int_1^\infty \dfrac{\cos(tx)}{x^3}dx
$$
Now, notice that
$$
    \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^3}dx = \dfrac{1}{2}
$$
Thus,
$$
    \varphi(t) = 1 - 2 \int_1^\infty \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx
$$
Since we only care about the behavior of $\varphi$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, we can assume that $0 < \vert t \vert < 1$. With this assumption, we split the integral into two:
$$
    \varphi(t) = 1 - 2 \int_1^{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}} \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx - 2 \int_{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}}^\infty \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx
$$
The second integral, notice that
$$
   0 \le \int_{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}}^\infty \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx \le \int_{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}}^\infty \dfrac{2}{x^3}dx = t^2
$$
Thus,
$$
    \int_{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}}^\infty \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx = t^2 O(1)
$$
Now, for the first integral, consider the Taylor expansion of $\cos$:
$$
    \cos(tx) = 1 - \dfrac{t^2x^2}{2} + t^4 O\left(x^4\right)
$$
So,
$$
    \int_1^{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}} \dfrac{1 - \cos(tx)}{x^3}dx = \int_1^{\frac{1}{\vert t \vert}} \left[\dfrac{t^2}{2x} + t^4O(x) \right]dx = \dfrac{t^2}{2} \ln\left(\dfrac{1}{\vert t \vert}\right) + t^2 O(1)
$$
Therefore,
$$
   \varphi(t) = 1 - t^2\left(\ln\left(\dfrac{1}{\vert t \vert}\right) + O(1)\right), \text{ as } t \rightarrow 0
$$

If I use the Taylor expansion I get $ t^2/2x - t^4O(x) $ not $t^2/2x + t^4O(x)$. How do you get the plus, since the minus is problematic?

@EnergySkiller The definition of Big-Oh is as follows $$ f(x) = O(g(x)), \text{ as } x \rightarrow 0, \text{ if } \exists \delta, M > 0, \vert f(x) \vert \le M g(x) \ \forall x, 0 < \vert x \vert < \delta $$ So if $f = O(g)$ then $-f = O(g)$

Thank you. I had an error in my reasoning.
